# Can not understand the code to plot Fourier Series approximation of the line

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I'm reading the CDF file from [Making Formulas… for Everything](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) in the WolframAlpha blog. I am confused by what's happening with In[9] and In[10].

Can anyone tell me what these two functions mean, or point out a book or documentation that I should read for reference? The expression in `fourierCoefficientLineSegment` looks quite different from the definition of fourier-series.

```
fourierCoefficientLineSegment[cs_, n_, {{t1_, x1_}, {t2_, x2_}}] := 
   With[{a = -(t2 x1 - t1 x2)/(t1 - t2), b = -(x2 - x1)/(t1 - t2)},
     If[cs === Cos, 
    If[n == 0, (t2 - t1) (2 a + b (t1 + t2))/2, 
       (-(n (a + b t1) Sin[n t1]) + n*(a + b*t2)*Sin[n*t2] - 
       b Cos[n t1] + b Cos[n t2])/n^2], 
    If[n == 0, 0, 
        (n (a + b t1) Cos[n t1] - n (a + b t2)*Cos[n t2] + 
       b (Sin[n t2] - Sin[n t1]))/n^2]]]

fourierSeriesLine[l_, n_, t_] := 
 Module[{ls, L, ts, xs, ys, Xs, Ys }, 
  ls = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[l, 2, 1];
  L = Total[ls];
  ts = 1. Prepend[Accumulate[ls], 0]/L 2 Pi - Pi;
  {xs, ys} = Transpose[l]; 
  {Xs, Ys} = Partition[Transpose[{ts, #}], 2, 1] & /@ {xs, ys}; 
  (Total[fourierCoefficientLineSegment[Cos, 0, #] & /@ #]/2 +
       Sum[
            Total[fourierCoefficientLineSegment[Cos, k, #] & /@ #] Cos[
          k t], {k, n}] +
       Sum[
        Total[fourierCoefficientLineSegment[Sin, k, #] & /@ #] Sin[
          k t], {k, n}])/Pi & /@ {Xs, Ys}]
```

Comment: I didn't see an In[9] on that page? It skips from In[8] to In[11] I believe?

Comment: @barrycarter, Download the .CDF file and open it, you'll see In[9] &In[10].